# crontab not running java

Tags: java, cron, executable-jar, ubuntu-server

I have a .jar which I can run perfectly via the command line.

I need this to be running continuosly every 5 mins, so i did crontab -e where I added this line

```
*/5 * * * * java -jar /var/www/java/executable.jar
```

if I go

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

I do see where the job was executed, but it never was since I have a logger inside the java file and the first thing it does is append to the logger the time, which is not doing so.

What can be the possible error?

Answer (score 2):

The most common error is that the environment-variables not bound and

1. java is not in path
2. JAVA_HOME is not set.

Try

```
*/5 * * * * java -jar /var/www/java/executable.jar > /var/log/javacron.log 2> /var/log/javacron-err.log
```

and inspect the `/var/log/javacron.log`-file for more informations.

Comment: Yes, even if runs using the commandline. The cron may use a different user or a different shell. If it runs a different user the java-exec may not allowed to work. If it runs a different shell you may have not the environment-variable-visibility in the cron-execution.

Comment: the file was generated blank

Comment: Ok, this is very interresting! I add a `2>` output to the answer, see the edit. The `2>` means the error-out. Usually a program can write into two seperate output, one for the normal messages (>) and one for the fatal-error-messages (2>). Retry it please.

Comment: @pato.llaguno I noticed you asked about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225771 , did you have any results in this question?

Comment: This is best solution i have even seen. follow this answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51137630/5093657